# need help on css float

Tags: html, css

Why only the first line of paragraph appears on the left and all other lines below the image when both the paragraph and img is floated?Here goes the code..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
   <style>
    img,p 
   {
    float:left;
   }
  </style>
  </head>

<body>
 <img src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84" />
 <p>
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

 </p>
```

But everything goes fine when only img is floated i.e all the text appears on left

Answer (score 2):

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mtJbD/1/)

Try this code:

```
<img src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84" />
 <p style="width:300px;">
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
 This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

 </p>​
```

Your code doesn.'t work because the element p doesn't have a width

If the floated element does not have a pre-defined width, it will take up as much horizontal space as required and available, regardless of the float. Note: some browsers attempt to place elements beside floated elements when the width isn't defined - usually giving the non-floated element only a small amount of space. So you should always define a width on floated elements.

Comment: p is a block level  element why r u using display:block to p tag ?confused!!

Comment: I have added it to block the width of the p but isn't necessary for the functionallity of the float @MaizerePathak

Comment: thanks for the post.It works but what is the reason for using width.What is difference in setting and not setting the width to p tag.plz explain

Comment: if you have solved  your problem accept the answer, is how stackoverflow works to help other person in future that have the same problem @MaizerePathak